# Explain please how to use WITH() in Kohana ORM

Tags: orm, kohana

```
$contract = ORM::factory('Contract', 1);
```

I can get shipper like this: `$contract->shipper;`
I can get owners like this: `$contract->owners->find_all();`

But I cant use

```
$contract->owners and preload them like ORM::factory('Contract', 1)->with("owners");
```

So why do I need this, I cant understand what it does, and how it works ?

Comment: I don't know why you want to, but how about adding a method like `withAll()` to ORM where you iterate the relationships and call `->find_all()`?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately `->with()` only works with `has_one` or `belongs_to` relationships, not `has_many`. The only way to expand many<->many relations is with `->find_all()`

From the `with` method description:

> Binds another one-to-one object to this model.

You can check the source code for the `with` function here: https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/ORM.php#L901